# Tornado store context during one request, or get current request handler?

Tags: python, tornado

I wonder if there's something like `flask.g` in Tornado, to easily share context between co-routines in one request. Or, may I just use the request handler object as the context, but how could I get the current one?

Answer (score 4):

Tornado does not provide an equivalent to `flask.g`. Things like thread-local variables do not work as usual in an asynchronous framework since everything is running on the same thread.

It is possible to build something analogous to a thread-local variable with a `StackContext`, but this is discouraged because it has significant overhead and some third-party libraries do not propagate stack contexts correctly. In most cases I would recommend explicitly passing the information you need to the places that need it instead of introducing this kind of magic. But if you think this is the best solution for your situation, see https://github.com/viewfinderco/viewfinder/blob/master/backend/base/context_local.py for an example.